Why does input data rate reduce with higher interpolation factors in interpolating DAC's
I am reading the specs of AD9152 and not entirely sure on how to interpret some information.
the diagram below shows that max input data rate (Which I interpret as the rate at which the DAC can accept data from JESD interface) reduce with higher interpolating factors? The main benefit of interpolating DAC's is to increase the bandwidth of the maximum analog out close to Nyquist limit (half the fdata in this case) by interpolating internally. If the fdata needs to be reduced when interpolation is introduced, two will cancel out and the benefit would be lost. The main benefit in this case would be that it is possible to have a lower data rate to produce a signal of a given frequency.

I wish to use the above DAC to create a 350MHz signal at each channel's output. However, due to fdata reduction, this looks impossible. Am I interpreting the DS and interpolation correctly?

It is limited by the internal DAC's maximum sample rate which is 2.25Gsps according to the datasheet.

The Interpolation Filters section of the AD9152 datasheet contains the following:

Note that fDATA = fDAC/InterpolationFactor

Based upon the Table 56. Interpolation Modes and Usable Bandwidth from the question and the above expression for fDATA, then for Interpolation Modes of 2x, 4x, and 8x fDAC is a maximum of 2250 MHz.
That agrees with the datasheet Table 2 in the Digital Specifications section:

On the assumption that fDAC in the limitation on how fast the DAC output can change, then it makes sense that as the amount of Interpolation increases the maximum fDATA decreases.
To answer the question, I believe you are correctly interpreting the datasheet for effect of the interpolation on fDATA.
The datasheet shows Coarse and Find Modulation followed by Inverse SINC or PFIR blocks after the interpolation. Haven't studied the maths to see if those blocks could help to generate the desired 350 MHz signal:

